# Find vocab word from vector for flexible comparisons

Tags: nlp, spacy

Is it possible to find a vocab word from a vector so that I can do more flexible comparisons?

Something like this:

```
queen = nlp.vocab["king"].vector - nlp.vocab["man"].vector + nlp.vocab["woman"].vector
king = nlp.vocab["queen"].vector - nlp.vocab["woman"].vector + nlp.vocab["man"].vector
queen.similarity(king)
```

I realize in this example I could just check the similarity of king and queen directly, but my use-case is that I'd like to compare sentence/doc similarity and I read that in order to get sentence vector I can simply add up the words in a given sentence and I'm assuming that means I can compare them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better then summing the embeddings of the words forming your sentence, you can use a sentence embedding model as [sentence-transformer](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers). This will give you :

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

e1 = model.encode(['This is your first sentence'])
e2 = model.encode(['This is your 2nd sentence'])

cosine_similarity(e1, e2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I'm assuming you could also use this for documents, or is there a better approach to that?

Comment: I haven't tried but this should give good results with documents / paragraphs too.

Comment: Results weren't bad